# any body know what framework msn front page developer use

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, frontend

I am now working on a huge site to developed it from scratch , but it should be light, fast , secure and optimize, for that i am looking to client side architecture, even the site is fully dynamic have millions of users and products. but still i want to use ajax , json and web services for quick response.
But i am interesting to use client side archeticture like yahoo , google , and msn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

know your needs before looking for tools and frameworks.

No one should consider what tool I should use, before knowing the requirements of the project.

write them down, know your skills, and from this point, start to look for the right tools .

Comment: @Mohammed-ElSayed You know  i developed such kind of application only jquery,json and webservices, nothing else , i have create pager and repeator inside javascript and json , but now i am looking for your recommendation . can i use javascript , json for large sites

Comment: Sure you can, dell, cnn, AlJazeera, all these sites depends on Javascript frameworks ( such as jQuery, MooTools and so on) to deliver partial updates to the end user.
and as you know, these are large websites with thousands of visitors every day.

so the simple answer is, yes you can.
another thing to mention here, the hardware of the hosting enviroment. cause many developers may use shared hosting for such big sites, and blam the tools for the slowness of the site. so pick your server configuration very well.

Comment: @mohammad-Elsayed thanks,i am using asp.net and sql , so can you tell me which framework msn or yahoo or google developer use.

Comment: yahoo uses YUI, dell I guess is using jQuery. I don't know what framework is being used in MSN, but considering that Microsoft is now fully supporting jQuery, I expect that tey may be using it in MSN too.